# Typedef of unique_ptr List

Tags: c++, list, unique-ptr

I'd like to make a typedef for `std::list<std::unique_ptr<>>`, so I could type `PtrList<A>` and it would be replaced by `std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>>`.

I know the way to do that with #define:

```
#define PtrList(x) std::list<std::unique_ptr<x>>
```

But I think typedef would be proper. However I don't know how to realize that. Could someone tell me how to typedef this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, try not to use `#define` to generate code. Except for conditional compilation, `#define` should be avoided.

A correct type alias:

```
template<class T> using PtrList = std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
```

Example use:

```
PtrList<int> intPtrList;
```

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
template<typename A>
using PtrList = std::list<std::unique_ptr<A>>;

PtrList<SomeStructure> myList;
```

Answer (score 3):

**In C++11:** use a template alias

```
template <class T>
using PtrList = std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

//later:
PtrList<int> myIntPtrList;
```

**in C++98/03:** There is no template alias, so in cases like this you will need a workaround. There is no `std::unique_ptr` either, so you obviously have C++11 already, but for the sake of completeness here is a C++03 example with a `shared_ptr` (i refuse to use `auto_ptr`, regardless of it is "more like `unique_ptr`"):

```
template <class T>
struct PtrList { typedef std::list<boost::shared_ptr<T>> type; };

//later:
PtrList<int>::type myIntPtrList;
```

Comment: Correct, but of course in C++98/03, there is not `std::unique_ptr` to begin with...

Comment: @Angew gotcha. The general problem of not having template aliases however exists ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of C++ (C++11) you can using *type aliases*:

```
template<class T> using PtrList = std::list<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
```